# double line breaks in html generate larger space

Tags: android, html

I'm trying to format text in android using HTML. Making use of two 
 in the string which I pass to Html.fromHtml creates a larger space whereas using single 
 generates a too short space. Screenshots attached.

**With single line break**
http://s8.postimg.org/nb332ru51/Screenshot_2015_03_07_21_31_30.png

**With double line breaks**
http://s8.postimg.org/a87gji3x1/Screenshot_2015_03_07_21_32_15.png

How can I have the spacing like the first four using HTML. I didn't find any way to change the spacing size of br in android.

The short piece of code is

```
    String text = "";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < numofCpus; i++) {
        text = text+"<b>CPU"+i+": <font color=#4CAF50>"+Utils.toMHz(Utils.fileReadOneLine(cpufreqpathraw.replace("raw", ""+i)))+"</font></b><br>";
    }
    myTextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: set some padding, it will work

Comment: I don't know how to set padding in html but you should try something like, `<div padding="5"> text+"<b>CPU"+i+":.... </div>`

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue. Using lineSpacingExtra of 10.0sp on the textView gives me what I need.